.NET API | Rewrites not working for existing URLs
I have a .NET 4.8 ASP.NET WebAPI, and we are migrating same to .NET 6, now as a part of migration plan we have planned to migrate endpoints controller wise for minimal impact on end users. Following is the architecture of current solution we have done.
Now e.g. our ASP.NET Framework API is hosted on abc.com domain and we have following 2 endpoints e.g. in it
https://api.abc.com/api/v1/test/data
https://api.abc.com/api/v1/test2/data2
We have hosted our new .NET 6 API on new domain as below
https://apiv2.abc.com/api/v1/test/data
https://apiv2.abc.com/api/v1/test2/data2
https://apiv2.abc.com/api/v1/test/data3
Add added a rewrite in our old framework app to rewrite only test controllers endpoint to rewrite to new .NET 6 endpoints
<rule name="Rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="api/v1/(test)/(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="https://apiv2.abc.com/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true"/>
</rule>

Now here is the actual problem, if I try to actual any existing API url e.g. https://api.abc.com/api/v1/test/data it is getting served from old .NET framework app only although the rewrite should work and rewrite it to new .NET 6 app. But if I hit a url which matches the rewrite but an endpoint is not present for that in Framework app, it rewrites to new .NET 6 app e.g.
https://apiv2.abc.com/api/v1/test/data3
I am not sure why is this happening and wanted some help in identifying the issue.

Your regex is wrong, ^ asserts the position is at the start of the string, remove it and your rewrite should work. FYI you can use a website like regex101.com to test your regex

Try removing the '^' character.  The '^" says to match at the beginning of the string and 'api' is not the beginning of the URL.

My bad - actually I have added ^ by mistake, in actual rewrite we do not have this. Updated question to reflect same

Try to use this rule <rule name="Rewrite" stopProcessing="true">   <match url="api/v1/test/(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />   <action type="Rewrite" url="https://apiv2.abc.com/api/v1/test/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true"/> </rule> ,and tell me it works or not.
